# Retrieve Data from a Specific Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Goal:
I want to retrieve the value of `[data].[Mobiles]` when you use a query document that is for the database `[test]` (`use [test]`)

Problem:
Based on picture two, I cannot retrieve the value from the database. Don't know what is the problem? The database `[wwtest]` is existing.

Picture 1:

[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2:
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: What's that `[dbo]` doing there? I thought `[data]` is the schema name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in your second picture you are using a 4-part name, which means:

> server . database . schema . object

So the query will fail because you don't have a `wwtest` server.

Assuming `[data]` is your schema name, you just need to change your query to:

```
use [test]

select *
from [wwtest].[data].[Mobiles]
```

and this will be recognized as:

> database . schema . object

More info: [Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx)